# Using Fragment: fragment class or view pager?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I using fragment like following:

```
Fragment fragment = null;
        fragmentClass = null;

        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.home:
                navItemIndex = 0;
                fragmentClass = HomeFragment.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_settings:
                fragmentClass = SettingsFragment.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_about_us:
                fragmentClass = AboutFragment.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_logout:
                fragmentClass = LogoutFragment.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_chart:
                fragmentClass = ChartPriceFragment.class;
                break;
            default: fragmentClass = HomeFragment.class;
        }

        try {
            fragment = (Fragment)fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, fragment).commit();
```

Should i continue using this. Or i should use view pager? though this method maybe slow.

....

Comment: What you are actually doing. explain it more.

Comment: Choice is yours, if you are using the tablayout then viewpager would be better choice.  if you are using the nav drawer to replace the fragment on the container.. current way is also good

Comment: In navigation drawer i using this method and changing fragment.

Comment: It is okay with your process

Comment: then if i not using tablayout is it good?

Comment: yeah totally cool

Comment: I wouldn't call this slow. If you want to nitpick this is linear time on 6 items (always so you could even argue constant) which is nothing significant timewise. Regarding your code design question, yeah this should probably be refactored into a viewpager. Especially if you navigate these fragments in a manner where the user feels they are next to each other.

Comment: Is there what difference view pager changing fragment and my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ViewPager is a class to manage more than one view like the time you want to use more than one Fragment on a page.
these are totally different 
this page can help you:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Answer (score 0):

switch can only change fragment in frame layout.
for view pager you'll need adapter for your view pager